# How come this question get closed? Who asked it anyway?

Tags: discussion

While browsing this meta site, i came across this question, the user who asked it is [community](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), i quote:

```
Hi, I'm not really a person.

I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!

I do things like

Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted
Own suggested edits from anonymous users
```

from what i understand, it's a bot, but it asked [this question](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238/lets-get-critical-may-2013-site-self-evaluation), how come a bot ask a question? And if `community` profile is used by  moderators, i mean if moderators used that account to ask the question, then how come other moderators close it? I'm confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The community user (which is indeed a bot and is *not* used by the moderators) is used, as described above, to do light background cleanup work on the main chess site, and there is a similar community user on every site that is part of the SE network. It is also set up to ask occasional questions, like the one you link to, on the *meta* side of the chess site only, not on the main site. The question you noticed was posted by the community user just to draw attention to the site's self-evaluation process, soliciting feedback from the user base. It was closed by Andrew as "too localized" after it had served its purpose and the site self-evaluation period had ended, making the post no longer relevant or useful.

Comment: ah ok thanks sir